# Invalid RSA Public Key error on Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, key, rsa, selenium-chromedriver

I am clicking on an element using selenium webdriver. As soon as i click on the element, my application opens the landing page and after 5 seconds, i receive 'Invalid RSA Public key' error. Cannot figure out what's wrong.

Here is the code:

```
lp.login_function(); //logins into the application
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("custSearchText")));
WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.id("custSearchText"));
x.sendKeys("graham"); //enters the client name 'Graham'
Thread.sleep(5000); //waits for 5 seconds   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btnSearchCust"))); 
WebElement y = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearchCust"));
y.click(); //clicks on search icon.
```

Now the page loads and after about 10 seconds 'Invalid RSA Public Key' error appears.

Comment: Can you share the concerned `URL`?

Comment: Is there any ither option? Because its not possible to share the URL since i am executing the test in my organisation’s internal network. Its a banking domain website. I hve not included any sorts of desired capabilities for chrome driver. Is that a problem?

Comment: Not adding any sorts of desired capabilities for chrome driver shouldn't be of any issue. But `'Invalid RSA Public Key'` error can be due to interaction with underlying technology pHp/DotNet/Python specific or something else.

Comment: Yes the website is built in dot net technology. But how can I as a tester handle this situation? I can run other tests on this application, but specifically in this case i get this error. Can there be a possibility that since its a banking application and i am trying to open a client profile, its restricting me as a security measure?

Comment: Can you paste the entire error stack trace?

Comment: That would not be possible too. . Have you ever faced anything like this before?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I need to know about your `Test Bed`.

Comment: I will be able to access the application after the weekend now. I will see what i can do. In the mean while i will try to research more.

Comment: Anyone else with a solution here?